# Nginx + PHP-FPM not interpreting PHP in .html files

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I have searched for days on this topic and read almost every SO thread on Nginx + PHP-FPM configuration. My configuration seems accurate. I am using Docker. Unfortunately, this site is old and I am the new maintainer of it. As you'll see, the `.htm/.html` files are not super easy to follow in their present format, but it does work on a remote server so I am relatively certain my local configuration is simply missing something.

My local site loads the homepage just fine, but any PHP within the `index.htm` file is printed directly:

[image]

Other pages that rely more heavily on PHP to render any HTML appear as pure PHP code printed to an otherwise blank document.

My `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile`:

*docker_compose.yml*

```
version: '3'
volumes:
  persistent-db:
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: ./docker-config/php-fpm
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./docker-config/php-fpm/www.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
      - ./docker-config/php-fpm/php-fpm.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/php-fpm.conf
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_HOST: ${MYSQL_HOST}

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13.8
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./docker-config/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - 3312:3306
    volumes:
      - persistent-db:/var/lib/mysql:delegated
    depends_on:
      - php
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
```

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

And the configuration in my `default.conf` file, for Nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html/docs;
    charset utf-8;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name dev.local;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location ~ \.htm$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.htm)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.htm;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/local_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/local_access.log;
}
```

And, finally, the actual template file that is trying to be rendered on the homepage:

```
<?
include "../inc/OLconfig.php";
include_once ("$docRoot/inc/common.php");
if(is_file("$docRoot/inc/droplistrental.html")){
    include_once ("$docRoot/inc/droplistrental.html");
}
session_start();

$con = getDBCon($db,$sqlServer);

$query = "SELECT MAX(bedroom), MIN(bedroom), MAX(fullBath), MIN(fullBath), MAX(sleeps), MIN(sleeps) FROM {$dbrental} where isActive='1'";
$result = mysql_query($query, $con) or die();
list($DEFAULT_MAXBEDS,$DEFAULT_MINBEDS,$DEFAULT_MAXBATHS,$DEFAULT_MINBATHS,$DEFAULT_MAXOCC, $DEFAULT_MINOCC) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
if (!$DEFAULT_MINBEDS) {
    $DEFAULT_MINBEDS = 1;
}
$DEFAULT_MINSTAY = 7;
$DEFAULT_MAXSTAY = 28;
if($DEFAULT_MINSTAY % 7 == 0 && $DEFAULT_MAXSTAY % 7 == 0){
    //assume weekly stays
    $DEFAULT_STAYINCREMENT = 7;
}else{
    $DEFAULT_STAYINCREMENT = 1;
}
if($DEFAULT_MAXSTAY > 21){
    //don't allow search for more than 3 weeks at this time
    $DEFAULT_MAXSTAY = 21;
}
$DEFAULT_MINOCC = $DEFAULT_MINBEDS;
$DEFAULT_MAXOCC = $DEFAULT_MAXBEDS * 2;
$DEFAULT_MINBATHS = $DEFAULT_MINBEDS;
$DEFAULT_MAXBATHS = ceil($DEFAULT_MAXBEDS / 2);

$Arrival = qryGenWeekendDropDown();
$Stay = qryStayDropDown('Stay',28,7,7);
$bedroom = qryNumericDropDown("Min_bedroom","9","1","1","Bedrooms");
$fullBath = qryNumericDropDown("Min_fullBath","6","1","1","Bathrooms");
$town = qryDropDown("city",$dbrental,"Town");
$location = qryDropDown("location",$dbrental,"Village");
$area = qryDropDown("area",$dbrental,"Distance to Beach");

$Units = "<select name='ID' class='qsrchfield' onChange='javascript:parent.document.location.href=this.value'><option value=''>Find A Specific Property</option>";
$query = "SELECT UnitID,address FROM $dbrental where isActive='1' and address<>'' ORDER BY address";
$result = mysql_query($query,$con) or die ();
while(list($UnitID,$name) = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    $Units .= "<option value='/rental/house.html?ID=$UnitID'>$name</OPTION>";
}
$Units .= "</select>";

$unitCodes = "<select name='ID' class='qsrchfield' onChange='javascript:parent.document.location.href=this.value'><option value=''>Find A Property by Number</option>";
$query = "SELECT UnitID,unitNumber FROM $dbrental where isActive='1' and unitNumber<>'' ORDER BY unitNumber";
$result = mysql_query($query,$con) or die ();
while(list($UnitID,$name) = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    $unitCodes .= "<option value='/rental/house.html?ID=$UnitID'>$name</OPTION>";
}
$unitCodes .= "</select>";

$price = "
<select name='Min_Price'>
    <option value=''>Price Range</option>
    <option value=''>Any</option>
    <option value='1000'>&lt; $1000</option>
    <option value='2000'>$1000 - $2000</option>
    <option value='3000'>$2000 - $3000</option>
    <option value='5000'>$3000 - $5000</option>
    <option value='6000'>$5000 +</option>
</select>
";

print "
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
<title>$clientName</title>
<link href='/css/stylesheet.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<div id='quickSearch'>
  <form id='search_form' name='search_form' action='/rental/query_p.html' method='post' target='_top'>
    <span id='weekend'>
    $Arrival
    </span>
    <span id='stay'>
    $Stay
    </span>
    <span id='bedRooms' class='floatLeft'>
    $bedroom
    </span>
    <span id='bathRooms' class='floatRight'>
    $fullBath
    </span>
    <span id='priceRange' class='clearFloat'>
    $price
    </span>
    <span id='town'>
    $town
    </span>
    <span id='location'>
    $location
    </span>
    <span id='beachDistance'>
    $area
    </span>
    <input type='submit' name='Submit' value=' Find My Rental ' class='button qsrch'>
  </form>
  <div id='qsrchLinks'><a href='/rental/query.html' target='_top'>Advanced Search</a> | <a href='/rental/alpha.html' target='_top'>View All</a></div>
   <span id='findName'>
    $Units
    </span>
  <div id='propIdWrapper'>
    $unitCodes
<!--
  <form action='/rental/query_p.html' method='get' target='_top'>
    <input type='text' name='PMSKey' placeholder='Enter Property Number' value='' id='propID'>
    <input type='image' src='/images/bttn-tiny.png' alt='Submit' class='floatRight'>
  </form>
-->
 <div class='clearFloat'></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
";
exit();

function qryDropDown($sendName,$dbtable,$Label=""){
    $outText = "";
    global $con;
    $chkVal = $GLOBALS["url_".$sendName];
    if(! $colspan){
        $colspan='1';
    }
    if($Label){
        $Label = "<option value=''>$Label</option>";
    }
    $outText .= "<select name='$sendName' class='qsrchfield'>$Label<option value=''>Any</option>";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT $sendName from $dbtable WHERE destination='".$GLOBALS['DESTINATION']."' AND $sendName <>'' AND $sendName <>'N/A' ORDER BY $sendName",$con);
    while(list($opt) = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
        $outText .= "<OPTION VALUE=".urlencode($opt);
        if($chkVal == $opt){
            $outText .= " SELECTED ";
        }
        $outText .= ">$opt</OPTION>";
    }
    $outText .= "</select>";
    return $outText;
}

function qryNumericDropDown($sendName,$end,$start=1,$step=1,$Label=""){
    $outText = "";
    $chkVal = $GLOBALS["url_".$sendName];
    if(! $step){
        $step = 1;
    }
    if(($start > $end && $step > 0) || ($start < $end && $step < 0)){
        return;
    }
    if($Label){
        $Label = "<option value=''>$Label</option>";
    }
    $outText .= "<select name='$sendName' class='qsrchfield'>$Label<option value=''>Any</option>";
    for($i=$start;$i<=$end;$i += $step){
        if($i == $start && $i > 1){
            $sendVal = "_".$i;
            $displayVal = "Up to ".$i;
        }elseif($i == $start){
            $sendVal = "_".$i;
            $displayVal = $i;
        }elseif($i == $end){
            $sendVal = $i."_";
            //$displayVal = $i." or More";
            $displayVal = $i;
        }else{
            $sendVal = $i."_".$i;
            $displayVal = $i;
        }
        $outText .= "<OPTION VALUE='$sendVal'";
        if($chkVal == $sendVal){
            $outText .= " SELECTED ";
        }
        $outText .= ">$displayVal</OPTION>";
    }
    $outText .= "</select>";
    return $outText;
}

function qryStayDropDown($sendName,$end,$start=1,$step=1)
{
    $outText = "";
    $chkVal = $GLOBALS["url_".$sendName];
    if(! $step){
        $step = 1;
    }
    if(($start > $end && $step > 0) || ($start < $end && $step < 0)){
        return;
    }

    $outText .= "<select name='$sendName' class='qsrchfield-sm'><option value=''>Length of Stay</option>";
    for($i=$start;$i<=$end;$i += $step){
        $outText .= "<OPTION VALUE='$i'";
        if($chkVal == $i){
            $outText .= " SELECTED ";
        }
        $outText .= ">$i</OPTION>";
    }
    $outText .= "</select>";
    return $outText;
}

function qryGenDateDropDown()
{
    $outText = "";
        $outText .= "<select name='ArrMonth' class='qsrchfield-sm'><option value=''>Mo</option>";
    for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){
        $tmp = sprintf("%02d",$i);
        $outText .= "<option value='$tmp'";
        if($GLOBALS['url_ArrMonth'] == $tmp){$outText .= " selected";}
        $outText .= ">$i</option>";
    }
        $outText .= "</select>&nbsp;<select name='ArrDay' class='qsrchfield-sm'><option value=''>Dy</option>";
    for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++){
        $tmp = sprintf("%02d",$i);
        $outText .= "<option value='$tmp'";
        if($GLOBALS['url_ArrDay'] == $tmp){$outText .= " selected";}
        $outText .= ">$i</option>";
    }
    $outText .= "</select>";
        $outText .= "&nbsp;<select name='ArrYear' class='qsrchfield-sm'><option value=''>Yr</option>";
    $yy = date('Y');
    for($i=0;$i<=1;$i++){
        $tmp = sprintf("%4d",$yy + $i);
        $outText .= "<option value='$tmp'";
        if($GLOBALS['url_ArrYear'] == $tmp){$outText .= " selected";}
        $outText .= ">'".sprintf("%02d",($tmp % 100))."</option>";
    }
    $outText .= "</select>";
    return $outText;
}

function qryGenWeekendDropDown(){
    global $url_Avail;
    $outText = "";
    $outText .= "<select name='Weekend'><option value=''>Arrival Weekend</option><option value=''>No Preference</option>";
    $dow = date('w');
    $dayOffset = 6 - $dow;//find next saturday date
    $month = date('m');
    $day = date('d') + $dayOffset;
    $thisyear = date('Y');
    $year = $thisyear + 1;
    $beginDateMonth = "05";
    $endDateMonth = "09";
    if($url_Avail){
        $Arrival = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("$url_Avail"));
    }
    if ( $dayOffset > 2){
        //if greater than 2 days out then show this saturday.
        $arriveDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+$dayOffset day"));
        $arriveDateMonth = date("m",strtotime($arriveDate));
        if($arriveDateMonth > $beginDateMonth && $arriveDateMonth < $endDateMonth){
            $outText .= "<option value='$arriveDate'";
            if($arriveDate == $Arrival){
                $outText .= " selected='selected'";
            }
            $outText .= ">" . strftime("%m/%d/%y",strtotime("+$dayOffset day")) . "</option>";
        }
    }
    for($i=1;$i<51;$i++){
        //For Saturday Date
        $dayOffset += 7;
        print "<!-- test  $i -->";
        if(date("Y",strtotime("+$dayOffset day")) == $year || date("Y",strtotime("+$dayOffset day")) == $thisyear){
            $arriveDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+$dayOffset day"));
            $arriveDateMonth = date("m",strtotime($arriveDate));
            if($arriveDateMonth < $beginDateMonth || $arriveDateMonth > $endDateMonth)continue;
            $outText .= "<option value='$arriveDate'";
            if($arriveDate == $Arrival){
                $outText .= " selected='selected'";
            }
            $outText .= ">" . strftime("%m/%d/%y",strtotime("+$dayOffset day")) . "</option>";
        }
    }//end for $i
    $outText .= "
    </select>
    ";
    return $outText;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who find this in the future, I found the solution. I had to add a `link` in my `docker-compose.yml` file to the php container:

```
 nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./docker-config/nginx/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
    links:
      - php
```

Then my `www.conf`:

```
[www]

user = www-data
group = www-data

listen = nginx:9000

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
```

And, `php-fpm.conf`:

```
security.limit_extensions = .php .html .htm .js
```

And, finally, my `site.conf` file for Nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html/docs;
    charset utf-8;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name dev.local;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    # Had to add for both .html and .htm
    location ~ \.html$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.html)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.html;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    # Had to add for both .html and .htm
    location ~ \.htm$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.htm)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.htm;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/local_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/local_access.log;
}
```